# Use Fourier Transform result to solve an integral

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a problem that says: find the Fourier Transform by definition of the function $f(t)$, being 
$$ f(t)= e^{-2 \vert t\vert } $$
Then, use this result to solve
$$  \int_{-\infty} ^{-\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2+2^2)^2}dx $$

I found that 
$$\mathscr{F}\{f(t)\}= \frac{2^2}{2^2+w^2}$$
But now I don't know how to relate this result with the integral

Comment: Parseval. ${}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat How did you get around the minimum character limit?

Comment: @LukasKofler: dollar { } { } { } dollar, if you see what I mean. But don't tell anyone :-)/

Comment: Nifty. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Using Parseval I reach that the integral diverge. Is that correct? I have doubts about it

Comment: How in the world does Parseval show the integral diverges? In this context it's actually "Plancherel", not "Parseval"  - do you know what the Plancherel theorem _says_?

Comment: +1 for your efforts Emiliano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathscr{F}\{e^{-2|t|}\}= \frac{4}{w^2+4}$$
$$\mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac {e^{-2|t|}}4 \right\}= \frac{1}{w^2+4}$$
Now by Plancherel's theorem you have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat f^2 (\xi)d\xi=2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\ f^2 (t)dt $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(\xi^2+4)^2}d\xi=\frac {\pi}8\int_{-\infty}^\infty\ e^{-4|t|}dt $$
You need to evaluate this integral:
$$
I=\frac {\pi}8\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4|t|}dt $$
$$I=\frac {\pi}8\left (\int_{0}^\infty e^{-4t}dt +\int_{-\infty}^0\ e^{4t}dt \right )   $$
$$I=\frac {\pi}8\left (\left | \dfrac {e^{-4t}}{-4} \right |_{0}^\infty+ \left |\dfrac {e^{4t}}{4} \right |_{-\infty}^0 \right ) $$
$$
I=\frac {\pi}8\left ( \dfrac 14+\dfrac 14 \right ) =\frac {\pi} {16}$$
Therefore:
$$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+4)^2}=\frac {\pi} {16}$$
As you see the integral dosen't diverge.

Comment: @Emiliano you're welcomed.......

Comment: @Emiliano i see what you mean...

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot. I didn't know Plancherel's theorem. The book I am using calls it in a different way. I didn't realize the way I had to relate the functions, I applied the property of symmetry of the transform and then I calculated the integral with that. Totally wrong

Comment: Just square the function $f(t)$ and multiply by a factor $2\pi$ @Emiliano

Comment: Thank you for your time @Isham

Comment: You're welcome Emilani glad to help you  @Emiliano